# Question about join conditions. Needing to compare number of shippings from point A to point B

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am needing to compare number of shipments from Destination A to Destination B. There are two tables, 1 and 2. Table 1 has the Destination A and Destination B column. Table 2 has a primary key code that ties to both column Destination A and Destination B on table1. My problem is that I am unsure on how to assign a specific value from table2's primary key onto "Destination A" and another specific value from table2's primary key onto "DestinationB".

For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table 2
ON table1.destinationA = table2_primarykey
WHERE table2.destination = "Chicago"
```

This will show me all rows from Table 1 that have destination key equivalent to the city of Chicago, which is half of what I am trying to do. The other half is setting a specific primary key value from table 1 onto "Destination B".

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table 2
ON table1.destinationA = table2_primarykey and table1.destinationB = table2_primarykey
WHERE table2.destination in ('Chicago','Seattle')
```

In the above query, I am trying to figure out how many shipments exist from origin Chicago to destination Seattle. The join condition above will not work for me as it will only show me Chicago to Chicago and Seattle to Seattle.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Why are you using an unsupported version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using TABLE2 twice, each time by joining with the corresponding destination column from TABLE1 and by selecting the required destination in the where section.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 A 
JOIN TABLE2 B ON A.DestinationA = B.PrimaryKey 
JOIN TABLE2 C ON A.DestinationB = C.PrimaryKey 
WHERE B.Destination = 'Chicago' and C.Destination = 'Seattle'
```

This query would map the Destination (from TABLE2) associated with DestinationA and DestinationB as if these are from different tables and selecting the corresponding destination in the WHERE section should give the desired result.

Comment: A pretty good answer but the `LEFT JOIN` is not needed and you should fix that.

Comment: Yeah, thanks Gordan for highlighting. I have edited the answer to replace the LEFT JOIN with JOIN.